# UIAlertAction's handler doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and now following a tutorial book. The book is kind outdated, and I had this bug.

Basically I'm trying to do a table cell selection, after I selected the cell it should pop up a menu and then I can hit the call button. However, right now after I hit the call button, the expected alter box doesn't show up, and the compiler gives me the error: ***Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior***

There is no bug when I edit the code, it just doesn't run correctly.

Another problem is that I have about 17 rows on the table, the stimulator's screen only shows 7 and I can't scroll down to see the rest of them.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath){

    //this creates an option menu when you tap on the row
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    //this is what happened after you hit the cancel option
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    //defines the action after tap on the call option
    let nocallAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    let callActionHandler = {(action:UIAlertAction!)-> Void in
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavaliable", message: "Sorry, the call is not avaliable yet, please retry later.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertMessage.addAction(nocallAction)
    }
    //this is what happened after you hit the call option
    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style:
        UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: callActionHandler)
    //this is what happened after you hit the been there option
    let isVisitedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "I've been here", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        })
    //add the action to the option menu
    optionMenu.addAction(isVisitedAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(callAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove "optionMenu.addAction(callAction)"?

Comment: You should create a separate question for your simulator problem if you can't get it to work. I'd try running it on a physical device to see if scrolling works first to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Sidetalker I tried on my iphone. It seems that the scrolling down does work, however after I scroll down the table, the app quit immediately, just like you hit the home button

Comment: @MingAn you should create another question. If the app is crashing (quitting immediately) something should be happening in the debugger - be sure to include that information. My blind guess would be that you're returning more rows in numberOfRowsForSection than your datasource is providing in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never present the view controller in the callActionHandler - it should look like this:

```
let callActionHandler = {(action:UIAlertAction!)-> Void in
    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavaliable", message: "Sorry, the call is not avaliable yet, please retry later.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertMessage.addAction(nocallAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Swift also allows you to create the completion handler at the same time as the UIAlertAction, which I think is more readable:

```
    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call " + "123-000-243534", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) 
    { action in
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavaliable", message: "Sorry, the call is not avaliable yet, please retry later.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertMessage.addAction(nocallAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```